# Symfony2 : form : pre_submit orders

Tags: symfony

I have 2 forms. One is the main form with fields and a collection and inside this fields the other form. On each form (the parent and the child) I add a PRE_SUBMIT subscriber. Now, my problem is, I want to load a method specific to the parent form after execution of the PRE_SUBMIT on the child event.
Actually, following the documentation, in spite I give priority, I have always this order :
`parent::PRE_SUBMIT -> child::PRE_SUBMIT`
and by the way I want :
`parent::PRE_SUBMIT -> child::PRE_SUBMIT -> parent::PRE_SUBMIT(other)`
Do you have an idea if it's possible to do that and in what way ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the event PRE_SUBMIT on your children (only add it for the parent), and inside your event handler do the specific code for your children.

E.g.

```
public function yourPresubmitMethod(FormEvent $event)
{
   $form = $event->getForm();

   // Code before

   // Code for each child
   foreach ($form as $child)
   {
      $child->theChildPreSubmitMethod();
   }

   // Code after
}
```

Comment: I will keep in mind this solution but I prefer another solution if that exists because I declare a `Valid:~` in the YML, that means my child form is with own logic and in this case, I'm not sure if it's in a "clean way".
What do you think about your solution for the "clean way" ?